# React-Native / Ionic (Cordova and Capacitor) Commands for Android & IOS

Tags: android, ios, react-native, cocoapods

Please provide some react-native or Ionic commands for android and ios

Answer (score 3):

1. Create React Native Project

   ```
              react-native init projectName
   ```
2. Run React-Native Project

   ```
              react-native run-android
                react-native run-ios
   ```
3. Create React-Native Module

   ```
       npm install -g react-native-create-library
       react-native-create-library your_library_name
             cd myLibrary
             npm install
   ```
4. Clean build cache

   Note:- android and ios both platform

   ```
        cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd .. && cd ios && xcodebuild clean && cd  ..
   ```
5. Install/Uninstall a package from npm

   ```
         npm install  your_library_name
         npm uninstall  your_library_name
   ```
6. Link/Unlink a package to react-native app

   ```
       react-native link your_library_name
       react-native unlink your_library_name
   ```
7. Recreate android and ios folder.

   ```
      react-native eject
   ```

   Error:- Unrecognized command "eject". info Run "react-native --help" to see a list of all available commands.

   ```
     react-native upgrade --legacy true
   ```

   Error: unknown option `--legacy'

   You can init a new project that's named the same in another folder and copy ios dir over:

   ```
    npx react-native init YourProjectName
    mv YourProjectName/ios ios
    rm -rf YourProjectName
   ```

   Make sure you have clean git history before doing so, in case you need to revert
8. Npm-cli-login

   ```
    npm install -g npm-cli-login
    npm-cli-login -u testUser -p testPass -e test@example.com
   ```
9. npm login (after successful login)

   ```
   npm publish
   ```
10. Clean cache and node modules and temp memory (for windows)

    ```
     del %appdata%\Temp\react-native-* & cd android & gradlew clean & cd  .. & del node_modules/ & npm cache clean --force & npm install & npm   start -- --reset-cache
    ```

Answer (score 1):

Rename React Native Package Name

> I use the react-native-rename npm package. Install it

```
npm install react-native-rename -g
```

Then execute the following:

```
react-native-rename "MyApp" -b com.mycompany.myapp
```

Answer (score 1):

Ionic Capacitor Commands

```
$ ionic start 
$ ionic start --list
$ ionic start myApp
$ ionic start myApp blank
$ ionic start myApp tabs --cordova
$ ionic start myApp tabs --capacitor
$ ionic start myApp super --type=ionic-angular
$ ionic start myApp blank --type=ionic1
$ ionic start cordovaApp tabs --cordova
```

Add a native platform to your Ionic project

```
$ ionic capacitor add android
$ ionic capacitor add ios
```

ionic capacitor build

```
$ ionic capacitor build android
$ ionic capacitor build ios
```

ionic capacitor copy web assets to native platforms

```
$ ionic capacitor copy android
$ ionic capacitor copy ios
```

Ionic capacitor run

Run an Ionic project on a connected device

```
$ ionic capacitor run android
$ ionic capacitor run android -l --external

$ ionic capacitor run ios
$ ionic capacitor run ios --livereload --external
```

ionic capacitor sync

Sync (copy + update) an Ionic project

```
$ ionic capacitor sync android
$ ionic capacitor sync ios
```

ionic capacitor update

Update Capacitor native platforms,
install Capacitor/Cordova plugins

```
$ ionic capacitor update android
$ ionic capacitor update ios
```